# How do you use git to sync iOS project between multiple computers

Tags: ios, git, version-control, xcode4, synchronization

This is my first post, and I will try to give as much detail as possible.  Just let me know what information you need to help me make my question more specific.

My current setup is as follows:

- Remote git repository on BitBucket (https://bitbucket.org/)
- Project source code on my laptop

I have git setup for my project and can commit locally as well as push changes to the remote repo.  I can clone a duplicate of my project to my laptop in the same folder and it works fine.

The problem I am running into is that I now have an iMac that I would like to use for development, and when I clone my project from BitBucket, I can access all of my source code but lose access to the third party libraries (in this case Three20).

I have tried to re-link the libraries on the desktop but I can't get it to properly link and build.

What is the best way to sync the source code of my projects between my two computers and still be able to use the external libraries on each one?

Comment: How are you linking the libraries? Are you including them in the git repo?

Comment: My libraries are stored locally in an iOS Libraries Folder.  They aren't included in my repo.  I found that the reason that they were not getting properly linked is that some of the files were referred to by their absolute paths not by relative paths.  After changing the paths to be relative to the project, I was able to get my setup to work by matching my relative setup with the directory path in the form ../../../API/library_name.

Comment: I am going to switch to using git submodules though because as Adam pointed out I think that is the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at chapter 6, section 6 of the progit.org/book. If you include 3rd party libraries as submodules, you don't bloat your repository while preserving what version of each library you are using.

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful.  I have been reading this book, but hadn't made it that far.  I figured out another way to get the links to work but this looks like the proper way to do it and I will setup my project to use submodules tomorrow.  Thanks!